# Is there a way to round very large fractions like 3.7625745528893614e-83?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, rounding, sigmoid

I have a large number of type float (3.7625745528893614e-83) which must go through the sigmoid function:

```
def sigmoid_one(x):#sigmoid computation function
 return (1/(1+math.e**(-x)))
```

,but after passing a large number (that is, a number with many characters after the decimal point) through the function, 0.5 is always obtained. For a solution, I wanted to try the round() function:

```
round(3.7625745528893614e-83,10)
```

, but after calculations it gives zero. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? maybe there is a replacement for the round () function or an alternative solution?

Comment: That's not a very large fraction. That's an extremely *small* number. Note the `e-83`, which means "times ten to the power of negative 83".

Comment: Why would you expect rounding to help?

Comment: That's standard-behavior of the logistic function. `sigmoid_one(0)` is 0.5 and your input is almost zero (close enough for internal rounding of `float` to remove the difference).

Comment: Not that it matters for this question, but you should never use `math.e**(something)`. Use `math.exp(something)` instead. It's more accurate, and likely faster, too.

Answer (score 1):

For small `x`, the function `exp(-x)` is about the same as `1-x`, so your function is approximately equal to `1/(2-x)` which, for small `x` is about `1/2`. So your program is working correctly.